# When to use the specified type of json-ld

Tags: seo, google, json-ld

I wanna to implement `json-ld` into my website, but I have some question about it, before I do that.

1. What `@type` should I use for a page with a list of sub-categories, also that page represent category page?
2. What is the best way to use `json-ld`. In one `script` tag or more? Does I need to generate `json-ld` for each element on the page? Or I can do that in single one `json-ld`? What is a better solution?
3. Should I need to combine `microdata` with `json-ld` or just to use `json-ld` as Google recommend it?
4. Also on website are product and articles, the articles are not blog type, they are information type, something how some `localBusiness` do thing. **Not** `HowTo`.
5. Also those categories(subcategories) are splitted, there are categories(subcategories) for products, and for articles. What `@type` should use for category(subcategory) of product and article?
6. Can I use information of company in `author` `@type`?
7. Does I need to have `BreadcrumbList` physically on the site in html or i can just implement `json-ld`? I know it's must have on html for all types. But i asking about `BreadcrumbList`.

[image: Website by hierarchy]

P.S. I googled in last two days, about those things. And i didn't find any good answer for each of those questions.

**P.S. It's a custom CMS**

Comment: It looks like Georg Keferböck was able to answer most of your questions, but in the future, this is a single Q & A site, so please limit your posts to one [reasonably scoped](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's plenty of questions. So, just to understand your question a little better - you want to implement "Schema.org" (Vocabulary), and wish to implement it using json-ld (Jason Linked Data), instead of RDFa or Microdata. Do I understand that correctly? If so -  here's my response:

1. See if https://schema.org/ItemList works for you - if not, don't tag it at all.
2. Multiple - this is an example I am familiar with taken from the Swarovski Store -

```
{
    "itemListElement": [
    {
        "item":
        {
            "name": "Jewellery",
            "@id": "c-01/Categories/Jewellery/"
        },
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 1
    },
    {
        "item":
        {
            "name": "Rings",
            "@id": "c-0106/Categories/Jewellery/Rings/"
        },
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2
    },
    {
        "item":
        {
            "name": "Hero Ring, Grey, Rose-gold tone plated",
            "@id": "p-M5372862/-/?variantID=5350665"
        },
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 3
    }],
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
    "@context": "http://schema.org"
}
```

```
{
    "offers":
    {
        "priceCurrency": "GBP",
        "@type": "Offer",
        "price": 49.5,
        "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock"
    },
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Hero Ring, Grey, Rose-gold tone plated",
    "description": "Be effortlessly stylish by day or night with this modern and feminine multi-layered ring in rose gold plating. A touch of black and white pavé creates an elegant contrast.",
    "@context": "http://schema.org"
}
```

3. Just use json-ld OR Microdata - do not do both. Preferrably json-ld as from a developers perspective it is easier to maintain.
4. I don't know what you mean by articles are NOT blog types. If that's the case you need to figure that out by yourself - a few possibilities: https://schema.org/Article, https://schema.org/blogPost, https://schema.org/BlogPosting, https://schema.org/DigitalDocument, etc.
5. There's no need to tag subcategories.
6. It will not throw an error, but I wouldn't. If for examply you have a blog post use the real Author. But again - it really depends what you are trying to do - there is no one right answer.
7. It is beneficial to have a physical breadcrumb list available - but it's not a make or break situation. Bread crumbs can be really useful to the site visitor - therefore I'd say yes - especially on a eCommerce store where you have user browsing your products within a specific cateogry. It's also beneficial to crawlers.

Comment: Yes, you'r right I wanna to use `Schema.org` (Vocabulary) by implementing json-ld.

4. I mean on page like this one http://jcms.pw/huyypw _(this is just example, its not mine)_. This is page about Plumber how they are checking water pipes by cam. Or something like this http://jcms.pw/s6bil  _(this is just example, its not mine)_. This is page about mobile service, and service of sim decoding phone. 

5. Can i use `itemList` for that also?

6. I had on mind page like in q 4. Maybe i should use publisher insted of author?

Comment: I made mistake with coping a link. Second link is http://jcms.pw/s6bil0

Comment: @NemanjaJeremic - you can - but in all honesty, if you are building a store, the only thing that matters is that you add structured data to services and products. So the answer is - yes you can, no doubt. How much impact it will have depends on what you actually wish to achieve. I would not tag any of the pages you presented with ItemList's as I wouldn't see a benefit. If you feel you should - it is best to refer to the description on Schema.org for each item. Hope this helps :)